# SonarQube build-wrapper doesn't create build-wrapper.json

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to run build-wrapper around my C code and it ran to completion without error, doing the build as it's supposed to do.  However, in the output directory, only build-wrapper-dump.json and build-wrapper.log are created.  There is no build-wrapper.json file.  My sonar-project.properties file:

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=GtiAnalys

#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=http://sonarqubedev:9000

# --- optional properties ---

# defaults to project key
#sonar.projectName=My project
# defaults to 'not provided'
#sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Defaults to .
sonar.sources=CSources

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# Properties specific to the C and C++ analyzer:
sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw-output

sonar.projectBaseDir=/export/home/binh/GtiAnalys
sonar.working.directory=/export/home/binh/GtiAnalys/sonar
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.language=c
sonar.inclusions-**/*.c,**/*.h
sonar.cxx.file.suffixes=.c
```

My command is:  build-wrapper-linux-x86-64 --out-dir build_wrapper make -f /export/home/binh/GtiAnalys/makefile -C ./CSources clean libGtiAnalys.so

Any ideas?  The make command without the build-wrapper works fine.  Thanks.

Comment: What's the underlying compiler?

Comment: The compiler is gcc

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I don't need this file.  Just the build-wrapper-dump.json seems to do the trick.